# Postgresql does not upgrade in my specified new data directory

Tags: postgresql

I uninstalled the postgresql (version 13.9) that comes with Debian repositories. Installed the postgresql-15 (version 15.3) from postgresql's Debian repositories and now want to upgrade my old cluster.

```
sudo pg_ctlcluster 13 main stop
sudo pg_ctlcluster 15 main stop
sudo pg_dropcluster 15 main
sudo pg_upgradecluster 13 main 15
```

It errors with insufficient disk space:

```
Upgrading database db1...
pg_restore: error: COPY failed for table "page": ERROR:  could not extend file "base/16387/16409.2": wrote only 4096 of 8192 bytes at block 264398
HINT:  Check free disk space.
CONTEXT:  COPY page, line 13796555
pg_restore: error: COPY failed for table "product": ERROR:  could not extend file "base/16387/16396": No space left on device
HINT:  Check free disk space.
CONTEXT:  COPY product, line 108
pg_restore: warning: errors ignored on restore: 2
Analyzing database alldatasheet...
ERROR:  could not extend file "base/16387/2696": No space left on device
HINT:  Check free disk space.
Error: Could not ANALYZE database
Error during cluster dumping, removing new cluster
```

My issue is that my 13 main cluster is on `/home/postgresql` I don't know why when upgrading, it creates it on `/15`, I don't have much space on `/` but a lot of space on `/home`.
I even specified new data directory:
`sudo pg_upgradecluster 13 main 15 /home/postgresql/15` but still creates it on `/15` and runs out of space during migration. I don't want to use link mode as that will create hard links.

Here's how my partitions look like:

```
df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            7.7G     0  7.7G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.6G  1.8M  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/sda2        23G   16G  6.6G  70% /
tmpfs           7.7G   16K  7.7G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
/dev/sda5       1.8G   87M  1.7G   5% /tmp
/dev/sda1       511M  5.8M  506M   2% /boot/efi
/dev/sda3       9.1G  6.9G  1.8G  80% /var
/dev/sda6       199G   57G  132G  31% /home
tmpfs           1.6G   96K  1.6G   1% /run/user/115
tmpfs           1.6G   88K  1.6G   1% /run/user/1000
```

I tried creating the target directory myself:

```
sudo mkdir /home/postgresql/15
sudo chown postgres:postgres /home/postgresql/15
sudo -u postgres pg_upgradecluster 13 main 15 /home/postgresql
```

But it errors with insufficient privileges:

```
Stopping old cluster...
Restarting old cluster with restricted connections...
Notice: extra pg_ctl/postgres options given, bypassing systemctl for start operation
Creating new PostgreSQL cluster 15/main ...
install: cannot change owner and permissions of ‘15’: No such file or directory
Error: could not create data directory; you might need to run this program with root privileges
Error: Could not create target cluster
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are failed with syntax of `pg_upgradecluster` command. Syntax of `pg_upgradecluster` you may check here: https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/pg_upgradecluster.8.html

According to that, it should look like:

```
sudo -u postgres pg_upgradecluster -k -v 15 13 main
```

with option `-k` to use hardlinks instead of copying old cluster files to new cluster data directory; option `-v 15` to pass new cluster version.